# Statically linked binary fails with "applet not found"

Tags: c, linux, embedded, busybox

I am running busybox v1.27.2 on an embedded linux system. To test my userspace build environment, I have cross compiled a simple hello-world application titled "hello". The system does not have library files available, so I have statically linked with uClibc. I have confirmed the binary was built correct using file:

```
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

when I try and execute from target rootfs, I get the following:

```
/ # ./hello
hello: applet not found
```

I have tried executing from /usr/bin and other directories, result is the same. I understand this message can occur when symlinks are not correctly pointing to busybox binary. However I am confused as this application should not depend on busybox. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code for reference:

```
// C library headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you copy the the hello program to the target system?  Where is it located?

Comment: @jwdonahue yes I made sure to copy to my rootfs before rebuilding & flashing kernel to target. Rootfs is mounted as initramfs. I have tried in various locations such as /usr/bin or /root, no change.

Comment: It may help if you post the output of `ls -l hello`.

Comment: here is the output run on the target `/usr/bin # ls -l hello 
-rwxr-xr-x    1    589555 hello
`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this buy re-compiling uClibc & "hello" binary with *arm-buildroot-uclinux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc* toolchain from buildroot